# echo or print_r array into placeholder of div

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

Okay, I am new to PHP so please forgive me. I know that is not common practice to include another div within a div placeholder but I am in need of some guidance on the best way to approach this task:

I have an input text field whose purpose is for users to enter their address, currently also using the google maps autocomplete api.

```
        <div class="r-street-address"><input id="Destination" tabindex="1" class="location txt_box" type="text" placeholder="Street Address, City, State"/></div>
```

So, the class 'location' includes a background image of an arrow. 
I am trying to change the content of the input id="Destination" from a text input, to instead print the result of the google maps reverse geocoding api.

For example:

```
 <div id="address2">Loading...</div><div id="city"></div>
```

These DIVS output the location in a formatted address.

Here I have set up an array:

```
<?php 
`$fullAddress = array(
"address2" => $_POST["address2"],
'city' => $_POST["city"]);
echo $fullAddress;
?>
```

I try to include the array result as a placeholder/value in the input field, like so:

```
<div class="r-street-address"><input id="Destination" tabindex="1" class="location txt_box" type="text" placeholder="<?php print_r($fullAddress);"/></div>
```

I also tried using echo, however both give me an output of ''array'' or the div class names.

Are there any suggestions on how I can best achieve the result I am looking for? Would it be best to pursue a CSS div class change onClick/mouseOver to just replace the input with instead another div formatted to contain the formatted address.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

I will also attach links to some JSfiddles I have been trying out to get the desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/ByLGs/
https://jsfiddle.net/e7fmcu3q/

Here is the javascript I am using for the reverse geocoding:

```
<script>
// set of locations represented by lat/lon pairs
var locations = [{
    lat: 43.73358,
    lon: -79.345334,
    place: "shops at don mills"
}, {
    lat: 43.424656,
    lon: -80.439038,
    place: "fairview park"
}, {
    lat: 43.777878,
    lon: -79.344654,
    place: "fairview mall"
}, {
    lat: 43.21735,
    lon: -79.86192,
    place: "lime ridge"
}, {
    lat: 43.8682046,
    lon: -79.2883119,
    place: "markville shopping centre"
}, {
    lat: 43.0260982,
    lon: -81.279526,
    place: "masonville place"
}, {
    lat: 43.806133,
    lon: -79.452095,
    place: "the promenade"
}, {
    lat: 45.4251736,
    lon: -75.6910829,
    place: "rideau centre"
}, {
    lat: 43.6104771,
    lon: -79.5605042,
    place: "sherway gardens"
}, {
    lat: 43.6536106,
    lon: -79.3800603,
    place: "toronto eaton centre"
}, {
    lat: 45.602224,
    lon: -73.564496,
    place: "galeries d anjou"
}, {
    lat: 45.464042,
    lon: -73.831361,
    place: "fairview pointe claire"
}, {
    lat: 45.5702429,
    lon: -73.7460388,
    place: "carrefour laval"
}, {
    lat: 45.5053826,
    lon: -73.3780708,
    place: "promenades st bruno"
}, {
    lat: 50.998577,
    lon: -114.074198,
    place: "chinook centre"
}, {
    lat: 51.0865228,
    lon: -114.1559935,
    place: "market mall"
}, {
    lat: 49.2828884,
    lon: -123.1182066,
    place: "pacific centre"
}, {
    lat: 49.1666477,
    lon: -123.135327,
    place: "richmond centre"
}, {
    lat: 46.0984068,
    lon: -64.7582975,
    place: "champlain place"
}, {
    lat: 49.881501,
    lon: -97.199779,
    place: "polo park"
}];

var geocoder;


function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            console.log(results);
            console.log(results[1]);
            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);

            if (results[0]) {

                //formatted address
                $("#address2").html(results[0].formatted_address)
                    //find country name
                for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                    for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {

                        //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                        if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                            //this is the object you are looking for
                            city = results[0].address_components[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //city data
                $("#city").html(city.short_name + " : " + city.long_name);


            } else {
                $("#address2").html("No results found");
            }
        } else {
            $("#address2").html("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}




function displayMalls() {
    var html = "";
    $.each(locations, function(k, v) {

        html += "<a href='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + v.lat + "&long=" + v.lon + "'>" + v.place + "</a><br>";
    });

    $("#malls").html(html);

}

$(function() {


    // displayMalls();

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


    // HTML5/W3C Geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(UserLocation, errorCallback, {
            maximumAge: 6000,
            timeout: 6000
        });
    } else {
        $("#latlong").html("GEO NOT AVAILABLE");
    }


    function errorCallback(error) {
        $("#latlong").html("GEO NOT AVAILABLE");
    }

    // Callback function for asynchronous call to HTML5 geolocation
    function UserLocation(position) {

        $("#latlong").html("Lat: " + position.coords.latitude + " <br>Long: " + position.coords.longitude);
        ClosestLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, "This is my Location");

        codeLatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    }

    // Display a map centered at the nearest location with a marker and InfoWindow.
    function ClosestLocation(lat, lon, title) {
        // Create a Google coordinate object for where to center the map
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        // find the closest location to the user's location
        var closest = 0;
        var mindist = 99999;

        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            // get the distance between user's location and this point
            var dist = Haversine(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon, lat, lon);

            // check if this is the shortest distance so far
            if (dist < mindist) {
                closest = i;
                mindist = dist;
            }
        }

        // Create a Google coordinate object for the closest location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[closest].lat, locations[closest].lon);

        var contentString = locations[closest].place +
            " <br>@" + Math.round(mindist * 10) / 10 + "kms";

        $("#result").html(contentString);


    }

    // Convert Degress to Radians
    function Deg2Rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    // Get Distance between two lat/lng points using the Haversine function
    // First published by Roger Sinnott in Sky & Telescope magazine in 1984 (“Virtues of the Haversine”)
    //
    function Haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var R = 6372.8; // Earth Radius in Kilometers

        var dLat = Deg2Rad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = Deg2Rad(lon2 - lon1);

        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(Deg2Rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(Deg2Rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;

        // Return Distance in Kilometers
        return d;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very basic question. echo gives you array because variable that you want to echo is array. If you want to print array then you can do several things.

1. Use loop like for, foreach etc.
2. Use implode() function to join array keys with some "glue" `echo implode(",", $fullAddress)`
3. Use array access for example `echo $fullAddress['city'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
$fulladdress = "Some address";
echo "<div class='r-street-address'><input id='Destination' tabindex='1' class='location txt_box' type='text' placeholder='$fullAddress'/></div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input id="Destination" tabindex="1" class="location txt_box" type="text" placeholder="Street Address, City, State"/>
```

edit placeholder to this:

```
placeholder="<?php echo $fullAddress; ?>"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is what I originally tried and it just prints out "<?php echo $fullAddress; ?>" in the input :) or ''Array''

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the array wasn't necessary. 1 simple line of js got the job done:

```
$('#Destination').attr('placeholder', results[0].formatted_address);
```